# POST to webpage in vb.net (win forms, desktop, not ASP.net)

Tags: php, vb.net, security, post

I have various PHP files which data is Posted to (like the password when the user signs in) How can I post to these PHP from vb.net (a desktop application that is Windows Forms, this is not about ASP.net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `WebClient` class. You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then use the `UploadData` method. The [documentation of that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a.aspx) contains a simple example, which basically boils down to this:

```
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Dim responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData("https://...", "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData))
Dim response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
```

The [Wikipedia page of HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) contains information of how the POST data must be encoded:

> Each key-value pair is separated by an '&' character, and each key is separated from its value by an '=' character. Keys and values are both escaped by replacing spaces with the '+' character and then using URL encoding on all other characters.

So, your `postData` variable can be filled like this (assuming that the fields you want to post are called Username and Password):

```
Dim postData = String.Format("Username={0}&Password={1}", _
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username), _
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password))
```