# Bypass user login (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

I have this application (Windows Form App) that require user to enter their Username and Password. Inside this application, there are shortcut for website and each of the website also require user to login first before they can use the website. But I want to **bypass** user when they click the shortcut for the website **(if they already login for the application)** where the login page will skipped and redirect user to the mainpage of the website. User will only required to login if they are accessing the website without using the application.

I used `Process.Start()` to run the website when the website shortcut is clicked. It open the website but redirect user to the login page. How do I bypass user credentials so that they will be able to login once (through the application) and can access all the website without do login again?

**Edit :** Is it possible if I use session inside my website login coding to redirect user to the main page? So it's like, when user login using the application, the website will automatically detect that the user already login, so user will be redirected to the main page of the website without going through the login page.

Comment: Do you have control on the website code? That is, can you change the website code?

Comment: Yes. The website is done by me but then I create another application to easier users to access into all the web. So the application that I made is like a menu where users need to login once then can use those website. User credentials info from those website using the same database for user credentials of the application.

Comment: Then you could pass an extra variable to the website when you redirect them, at the website, check if it is set, then no_need_to_login else go_to_login ? Not very safe though.

Comment: I don't have any idea on how to do that.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705201/how-to-open-ie-with-post-info-in-c) is in C#, but maybe you could get some ideas from it?

Comment: I think that post is not related to my problem.

Comment: You will need to authenticate the user again at the web site level, but instead of the user retyping in their credentials, you would have the client WinForms application pass the credentials to the server application. There are many different ways to do this and you would want to use HTTPS most likely.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Just passing an extra variable wouldn't be a viable solution for security reasons. See my comment above for answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for your reply. I will try it first.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I agree, that is why i added "Not very safe though. ". As you said, there are many ways to do this. The fact that the DB is same for user credentials makes it a bit more easier. Unless the OP decides on a path and tries something, there is not much anyone can do.

Comment: @Emerald See this post: [PHP Session when using desktop app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616822/php-session-when-using-desktop-app) It is for login to a PHP site, but the concept will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Give your user an API key that is stored in the user database table that is unique that changes when they login. Then in VB use `Process.Start("https://example.com/login.php?api_key=" + 'add api_key retrieved from database on login)` then in your PHP you check for the `api_key` as a login that will create the session for the logged in user.