# How to receive a http web request on a windows form application

Tags: vb.net

How can one pass http get or post methods to a windows application? I require a webserver to send a get method to my windows form application that will query a database then reply back to a webserver

I'm developing a windows based search engine that searches a MySQL database. It receives a keyword from an SMS gateway software as a HTTP get request and should reply to the gateway software using the same HTTP request.This is my code. It is correctly searching the database but I don't know how to receive the get methods on the application however it's sending the messages to SMS gateway.

```
Private Sub bSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bSend.Click
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim url As String
    Dim username As String = "admin"
    Dim password As String = "abc123"
    Dim host As String = "http://127.0.0.1:9501"
    Dim originator As String = "0724116972"

    Try

        url = host + "/api?action=sendmessage&" _
                 & "username=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username) _
                 & "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password) _
                 & "&recipient=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tbReceiver.Text) _
                 & "&messagetype=SMS:TEXT" _
                 & "&messagedata=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tbMessage.Text) _
                 & "&originator=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(originator) _
                 & "&serviceprovider=" _
                 & "&responseformat=html"


        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        MessageBox.Show("Response: " & response.StatusDescription)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error. Server Not running")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Yes, you can write an application that responds to web requests.  You'd essentially be writing a web server.  Then you have another web server which is going to issue the requests?  Web servers generally respond to requests, not issue them.  It's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish or why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615335/post-to-webpage-in-vb-net-win-forms-desktop-not-asp-net

Comment: Please check the example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you want to host a webserver in your winforms application...you can use `HttpListener` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

IF your application is not running as Administrator you will need to register the URL you are listerning to with `netsh` though