# Remote post to webpage from windows service

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net, windows-services, httpresponse

NOTE: *This question has been edited what was originally asked*

I'm developing a windows service that, daily, queries a web service for data, compares that to currently existing data and then posts it to the client's webpage.

The code for the remote post executes fine, but updates never happen on the client's web page...

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Public Class RemotePost

    Public Property Inputs As New NameValueCollection()
    Public Property URL As String
    Public Property Method As String = "post"
    Public Property FormName As String = "_xclick"

    Public Sub Add(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
        _Inputs.Add(name, value)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Post()
        Dim client as New WebClient()
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim responseArray = client.UploadValues(URL, Method, Inputs)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I believe the reason for this is that the post generated by the above code is different to what the form itself posts manually.

Here's an example of a post generated by the above code:

```
POST http://www.thisdomain.com/add-event/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: thisdomain.com
Content-Length: 116
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

no_location=0&event_name=Cycle-Fix+MTB+Tour+-+3+Days+ABC&event_start_date=2013%2f04%2f06&location_state=Eastern+Cape
```

And here's an example of a post generated on the page itself:

```
POST http://www.thisdomain.com/add-event/ HTTP/1.1
Host: thisdomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2844
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://thisdomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Referer: http://thisdomain.com/add-event/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Cookie: wp-settings-1=m5%3Do%26editor%3Dtinymce%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26align%3Dleft%26urlbutton%3Dnone%26imgsize%3Dfull%26hidetb%3D1%26widgets_access%3Doff; wp-settings-time-1=1367827995; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_8d8e9e110894b9cf877af3233b3a007b=admin%7C1368089227%7C69a33748ee5bbf638a315143aba81313; devicePixelRatio=1

------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="event_name"

test event
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="event_start_date"

2013-05-07
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="event_start_time"

01:00 AM
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="event_end_time"

02:15 AM
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recurrence_freq"

daily
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recurrence_interval"


------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recurrence_byweekno"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recurrence_byday"

0
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recurrence_days"

0
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_latitude"

38.0333333
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_longitude"

-117.23333330000003    

------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_name"

test
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_address"

test
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_town"

test
------WebKitFormBoundary8u14QB8zBLGQeIwu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_state"

Georgia
```

Clearly there's a lot more happening with the form's post than is the case with mine. Unfortunately, I'm afraid I don't understand all of it.

I have the following concerns about these differences:

- That my (apparently) querystring data is not being read because it's not being sent correctly ($_GET as opposed to $_POST)
- That there is possibly validation code in the PHP that saves the data after this post that is blocking it somewhere

Can anyone explain what exactly the differences here are and how I can emulate the form's post as per my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it just print html. It does not post.

Check out this question.

[POST to webpage in vb.net (win forms, desktop, not ASP.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615335/post-to-webpage-in-vb-net-win-forms-desktop-not-asp-net)

By using the WebClient class, you can send the information you want to a website.
The post data will be in the form of:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Inputs.Keys.Count - 1
    if postData <> "" Then postData &= "&"

    postData &= Inputs.Keys(i) & "=" & Inputs(Inputs.Keys(i))
Next
```

Comment: Okay so this is working... sort of. It turns out the form I'm posting to requires form data to work with which this is passing it querystring data. Got any suggestions for the swap?

Comment: Post data is passed using the postData variable (3rd parameter).
Querystring data is passed at the end of the url (1st parameter).

http://www.example.com/?data1=value1&data2=value2

Comment: Yes I can see that, but there's something going wrong. It posts to the page, but from there it's not getting used. Request data from the form itself that i see in Fiddler seems to be formatted differently to what the remote post is sending

Comment: Please review the question again. I've updated it to illustrate my current problem

Comment: @Ortund The form must be sending the data as "multipart/form-data". I don't know enougth about this to help... http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2